# how to hide Empty UITableViewcell Label with using json?

Tags: json, uitableview

hi i need to hide empty UITableViewcell label in custom TableView.i am trying to display JSON webservice values in custom tableviewcell.
   my json vales are looks like  ...

```
  (
    {
    post =         {
    "CLASS_LEVEL" = "Intro/General";
    "CLASS_TYPE" = "Muay Thai";
    "DAY_OF_WEEK" = "";
    ID = 19;
   "ORDER_BY" = 5;
   TIME = "1:00pm - 2:30pm";
    };
 }
   {
    post =         {
    "CLASS_LEVEL" = "General/Intermediate/Advanced";
    "CLASS_TYPE" = "Muay Thai Spar - Competitive";
     "DAY_OF_WEEK" = "";
     ID = "";
    "ORDER_BY" = 5;
    TIME = "6:00pm - 9:00pm";
    };
   },

   {
     post =         {
    "CLASS_LEVEL" = "Fighters/Advanced/Intermediate";
    "CLASS_TYPE" = "Fighters Training";
    "DAY_OF_WEEK" = Monday;
    ID = 1;
    "ORDER_BY" = 1;
    TIME = "";
    };
    },
```

i need to auto size my table cell dynamically .

here some of values are empty that values assigned label in tableviewcell want to be hidden.

is it possible? help me .Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

To hide the UILabel you can just do `cell.label.hidden = YES;`

Comment: i want to check label json values null and hide that label.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
NSString *dayOfWeek = ... ;

if(dayOfWeek == (id) [NSNull null] || [dayOfWeek length] == 0 || [dayOfWeek isEqualToString:@""])
{
    cell.label.hidden = YES;
}
else
{
    cell.label.hidden = NO;
}
```